# Pregel BSP: Difference between partitioning and assignment of user input by master to worker

Tags: graph, parallel-processing

The pregel paper mentions:

> a) The Pregel library divides a graph into partitions, each consisting
>   of a set of vertices and all of those vertices’ outgoing edges...**The
>   master determines how many partitions the graph will have, and assigns
>   one or more partitions to each worker machine**.

and

> b) **The master assigns a portion of the user’s input to each worker**. The
>   input is treated as a set of records, each of which contains an
>   arbitrary number of vertices and edges. **The division of inputs is
>   orthogonal to the partitioning of the graph itself, and is typically
>   based on file boundaries**.

I have two questions here:

1) In b), how is the master assigning a "portion of the user's input to each worker" different from "assigns one or more partitions to each worker machine". Do they have different functions? 
I thought we have to figure out our partitions and then feed one or more partition to a worker machine and that is all. What am I missing?

2) If the division of inputs is solely based on file boundaries, does that mean vertices of a partition can reside on different machines? (because two vertices of a partition may reside on different files and hence be processed by different worker machines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

The master assigning the user input to each worker is the same to assigning one or more partitions to each worker machine.

The user input will be a graph. This graph will be split into several partitions. These partitions will be split between workers.
The worker is where the partitions are going to be processed. They may contain one or more partitions. The partitions contain vertices. The partition in the entity selects active vertices and run their superstep computations.

**Question 2:**

No. All vertices that are inside a partition are inside the same worker. If a vertex is going to be transferred to another machine (and thus another worker), it will change to another partition.